# What is the most efficient way to find the coefficient before the $n$-th term in this generating function?

Tags: power-series, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, formal-power-series, infinite-matrices

I am calculating the square of the Pascal matrix (i.e. the infinite lower triangular matrix with entries $A_{nk}={n\choose k}$) using the theory of [Riordan arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riordan_array), and have obtained (or so I believe) the generating function for its $k$-th column:
$$\frac{1}{1-2t} \left( \frac{t(1-t)}{1-2t} \right)^{k}$$
Now, to calculate the element $A_{nk}$, I need to obtain the explicit formula for the $n$-th coefficient of this generating function,
$$[t^{n}]\frac{1}{1-2t} \left( \frac{t(1-t)}{1-2t} \right)^{k}=(*)$$
which looks like a dounting problem, unless I miss some clever way to do that. I've tried using the properties of the coefficient operator $[t^n]$, and have obtained

$$(*)=[t^n] t^k \frac{1}{1-2t} \left( \frac{1-t}{1-2t} \right)^k=[t^{n-k}] \frac{1}{1-2t}\left( \frac{1-t}{1-2t} \right)^k=$$
$$=[t^{n-k}] (1-t)^k \frac{1}{(1-2t)^{k+1}}$$
$$=\sum_{m=1}^{n-k} [t^m](1-t)^k[t^{n-k-m}] \frac{1}{(1-2t)^{k+1}}$$
$$=\sum_{m=1}^{n-k}(-1)^{m}{k \choose m}[t^{n-k-m}] \frac{1}{(1-2t)^{k+1}}$$

but I am not sure what should I do next and if this is the right path at all.

**Edit:** I have remembered the formula

$$\frac{1}{(1+z)^{\alpha}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\alpha)^{(k)}}{k!}z^k$$
where $(\alpha)^{(k)}$ denotes the rising factorial, hence,
$$\frac{1}{(1-2t)^{k+1}}=\sum_{d=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^d2^d(k+1)^{(d)}}{d!}t^k$$
and we have
$$=\sum_{m=1}^{n-k}(-1)^m {k \choose m}(-1)^{n-k-m}2^{n-k-m} \frac{(k+1)^{(n-k-m)}}{(n-k-m)!}$$
$$=(-1)^{n-k}\sum_{m=1}^{n-k}{k \choose m}2^{n-k-m} \frac{(k+1)^{(n-k-m)}}{(n-k-m)!}$$

But I still have no idea how to transform this into something understandable. Since the problem itself is taken from the first problem set to an enumerative combinatorics course, given out before the introduction of generating functions, the answer should be more or less nice.

**Edit 2:**
Using the identity ${-n \choose k}={n+k-1 \choose k}(-1)^k$, I managed to further "simplify" the expression to
$$(-1)^{n-k}\sum_{m=0}^{n-k}2^{m}{k+m \choose m}{k \choose n-k-m}$$

Still don't understand if this is simplifiable any further, and if the overall strategy was right.

**Edit 3:**
Tried to follow the advice by @Marko_Riedel and calculating the residue of $(*)\frac{1}{t^{n+1}}$ at $1/2$. Unfortunately, this does not seem to look simple:

$$\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{m=0}^{k}{k \choose m}\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^{m}\frac{1}{t^{n-k}}\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^{k-m}(1-t)^{k}$$ evaluated at $t=\frac{1}{2}$
$$=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{m=0}^{k}{k \choose m}(-1)^m (n-k)^{(m)}2^{n-k-m}\sum_{d=0}^{k}{k\choose d}(-1)^{d}(d)_{k-m} \frac{1}{2^{d-k-m}}$$

I am too tired to check r.n., but it appears to me that by Vandermonde's convolution this can be shown to be exactly the previous formula up to a sign.

Comment: You can do it by computation of a certain complex integral $\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)dz }{z^k}$ using residues. Have you heard about this method ?

Comment: While skimming several books on generating functions, I've noticed that one can use the calculus of residues and the mountain pass method (though mostly to calculate asymptotics), but I have never used complex analysis in combinatorics, and am not sure if I understand how to do that. Thanks for the hint, I'll try it.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3052732/305862)  for example.

Comment: Well, the way I understand it, this does not simplify the problem. Since the function in question has a zero of degree $k$ at zero, the $n$-th term in the Laurent series around zero is just the $n-k$'th term of the Taylor series of $$\frac{(1-t)^k}{(1-2t)^{k+1}}$$, and the formula for the residue gives precisely the definition of this term, i.e. it is simply $(n-k)$'th derivative at zero divided by $(n-k)!$

Comment: You can use the fact that residues sum to zero on your formula (*) and evaluate it with the  residue at one half. Note that the OEIS does not give closed forms so maybe you need to re-think your approach.

Comment: In the example you provided, the key ingredient was the fact that square root has a branch point, the values of the function at the top and at the bottom bank of the branch cut don't coincide, and one can calculate a line integral in two ways, directly and using the residue, thus finding the value of the residue. But in my case the function is meromorphic.

Comment: To use the fact that residues add up to zero, I would need to calculate the residue at infinity, which appears to be no simpler than calculating the residue at zero. Calculating the residue at one half is also essentially equivalent to calculating the value of the $n$-th term by brute force. P.S. What sequence at OEIS are you talking about?

Comment: Note that the branch point and the branch cut of the square root are outside the small circular contour and the function is analytic there. The residue at infinity of (*) is zero by inspection.

Comment: [OEIS A055852](https://oeis.org/A055852) and [OEIS A049600](https://oeis.org/A049600).

Comment: Ah, yea, you are right that there is obviously no singularity at infinity, and the residue at one half is sufficiently simpler to calculate. Gimme a sec to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151031/discussion-between-daigaku-no-baku-and-marko-riedel).

Comment: Good luck with your work. Off line for the day.

Comment: So, anyway, the proposed method does not appear to solve the problem